# Datatables plugin for jQuery throws 404 error on json resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I just installed Datatables, added some resources, but it throws me this errors

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/data/orders/newnew.json?_=1473851543931 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
>
> http://127.0.0.1:5000/data/orders/newprocessing.json?_=1473851543932 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
>
> http://127.0.0.1:5000/data/orders/newprocessing.json?_=1473851543932 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

Any ideas to fix it?

I'm not sure that **newnew.json**, **newprocessing.jso**n is correct. It should be **new.json**, **processing.json**.

Comment: Could you provide links to said jQuery database plugin?

Comment: @N.J.Dawson I'm not sure, which one do you mean? I bought this admin template so i don't know much about its structure

Comment: It's Datatables plugin, i had wrong title.

Comment: Show your DataTables initialization code where you call `DataTables({ })`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug.

First of all, there was a bad way to json resources. Script with default way was `api.ajax.url('data/orders/new' + orders +'.json');`

So i changed it to

`api.ajax.url('data/orders/' + orders +'.json');`

And second problem was with flask. I had to add static/ before data. Like this

```
api.ajax.url('static/data/orders/' + orders +'.json');
```